# How to use a dictionary inside of a while loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I'm trying to make a trivia game and this is the code that I have so far. I'm having trouble incrementing the players scores on this game. I'm using a while loop to try and increment the players scores and if player 1 gets the question wrong then it's player 2's turn but I don't know how to switch between the two. I have a "answer" variable where the player is going to input the value at. Inside of this while loop I'm trying to say that when the "answer" is equal to the correct answer; I want you to do the following, and when the "answer" is not equal to answer then do the following. I'm trying to grab the corresponding value from my answers dictionary but I don't know how to grab it. "answers [key]" is giving me an error, I need to type something else in instead.

```
player_1_points = 0
player_1 = input("Enter in your name Player 1: ")

player_2_points = 0
player_2 = input("Enter in your name Player 2: ")

questions = {'one' : 'What is the tallest mountain in the world?'}

choices = {'a' : 'A. Mount Everest', 'b' : 'B. Mount St. Helens', 'c' : 'C. Mount Vesuvius', 'd' : 'D. K2'}

answers = {1 : {'Answer': 'A'}}

print(questions['one'])

print(choices['a'], choices['b'], choices['c'], choices['d'])

answer = str(input("Answer is: "))


while answer == answers[key] :
  if player_1 == answer :
    player_1_points += 1
    print("Correct Answer!")
    print(player_1, player_1_points)
    print(player_2, player_2_points)
    
  elif player_2 == answer :
    player_2_points += 1
    print("Correct Answer!")
    print(player_1, player_1_points)
    print(player_2, player_2_points)
  
while answer != answer[key] :
  if player_1 != answer :
    print("Incorrect, Player 2's Turn")
    print(answer)

  elif player_2 != answer :
    print("Incorrect, Player 1's turn")
    print(answer)
```

Comment: First, welcome to StackOverflow ;) Second, what's `key`? Third, is there a reason `answers` has a dict inside a dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I changed your code.

```py
player_1_points = 0
player_1 = input("Enter in your name Player 1: ")

player_2_points = 0
player_2 = input("Enter in your name Player 2: ")

# now questions is a list of dictionaries
questions = [
    {
        'question': 'What is the tallest mountain in the world?',
        'option a': 'A. Mount Everest',
        'option b': 'B. Mount St. Helens',
        'option c': 'C. Mount Vesuvius',
        'option d': 'D. K2',
        'answer': 'A. Mount Everest'
    }
]

# you can add more questions to above list of questions


# loop through list of questions 
for question in questions:
    print(question['question'])
    print(question['option a'])
    print(question['option b'])
    print(question['option c'])
    print(question['option d'])

    # ask player 1 to enter their answer
    player_1_answer = input("Enter you answer Player 1 : ")
    if player_1_answer == question['answer']: 
        print('Correct Answer!')
        player_1_points += 1
    else:
        print('Incorrect Answer!')

    # ask player 2 to enter their answer
    player_2_answer = input("Enter you answer Player 2 : ")
    if player_2_answer == question['answer']:
        print('Correct Answer!')
        player_2_points += 1
    else:
        print('Incorrect Answer!')

# print scores for each player at the end
print(player_1, player_1_points)
print(player_2, player_2_points)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I wanted to know if you could do this with a while loop.

Comment: I wanted to have questions in one dictionary and choices in another and answers in another dictionary, so I can references them easier. Do I have to put everything in one dictionary?

Comment: I have put all in one dictionary, because its easier to access (for me). You can put them in different dictionaries.